# Carat Z symbol in text file

Tags: python, regex, vim, text, encoding

Does anyone know what a ^Z symbol in a text file represents and how I might go about cleaning that (regex/python?).

example string:

```
5411 Grocery Stores,www.sentryfoods.com,WI,6am ^Z 11pm 7 days a week
```

How can I find this with regex in vim or adapt the below python command to treat?

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', x))
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't really help me with removing it from my text file. Any possible suggestions?

Comment: Are you removing the rendered text `^Z`, or the original `x1A` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what ^Z means, but you will not find it by looking for `'[^a-zA-Z]'`. ^Z is a special character, and its not literally equal to "^Z". Also, in regex `'[^a-zA-Z]'` means a character other than a-z, A-Z (a non alphabetic character). It does not mean ^ then Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent it in a string with `\x1a`, or `chr(26)` in Python, so you can just do something like `s.replace("\x1a", "")`. What it actually means depends on the file type  (e.g., Ctrl-A is sometimes used as a field delimiter when pipes, tabs, commas, etc. don't work for whatever reason).

Comment: Thanks alot for this!. Works.

Answer (score 0):

`^Z` is `<C-z>`. You can insert it in the command-line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. In Vim's notation, that would be `<C-v><C-z>` so…

```
:%s/<C-v><C-z>/foo/g
```

would substitute all your `^Z` with `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt- but needs removing space.

```
re.sub('\^Z', '', x)
```